# Owl Carousel mousewheel Slider

Tags: html

thanks for great plugin!

I'm using Owl Carousel 2 with mousewheel.js. it's working fine, but when I set loop: false and I scroll to last or first item my mouse not working, how can I make mouse back to page scrolling when I go to first or last item ?

For example:

My slides : 1 2 3 4 5

Set loop: false and using mousewhell

When I scroll to slide 5 I want to scroll down of the page, not return to slide 1. Also scroll up of the page when I scroll to slide 1.

Can we do that?
Thanks for support !